# How to reduce the log verbosity of ansible based Kubernetes operator deployment from INFO to WARN or ERROR

Tags: kubernetes, logging, ansible, verbosity, kubernetes-operator

I have a wrote an ansible based kubernetes operator and I am trying to figure out a way to reduce the log generated by the operator deployment pod by reducing the log verbosity level.

> kubectl logs netqedge-7f8885fb85-5jk9c

netqedge is the ansible based operator

Operator Logs

````
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0016239,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/version","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0037427,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/version/openshift","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0057838,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0111895,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/api/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.014386,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/apiregistration.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0161085,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/apps/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0179722,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0196064,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.021108,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/autoscaling/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0225985,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/batch/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0239842,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0253205,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.026974,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0284228,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0300376,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0317163,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/scheduling.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0351508,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0369577,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.038904,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator.netqapp/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0419142,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator.netqcentral/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0439467,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator.netqclustermanager/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.046197,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator.netqedge/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0479949,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/com.cumulus.netq.operator.netqkafka/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0496933,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/crd.projectcalico.org/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}
{"level":"info","ts":1620286574.0518043,"logger":"proxy","msg":"Skipping cache lookup","resource":{"IsResourceRequest":false,"Path":"/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1","Verb":"get","APIPrefix":"apis","APIGroup":"","APIVersion":"","Namespace":"","Resource":"","Subresource":"","Name":"","Parts":null}}```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think `--zap-log-level` is what you are looking for.

It looks like this documentation isn't correctly in place, but you can look at the go documentation. I've also filed an issue for the Ansible docs.

https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/references/logging/#setting-flags-when-deploying-to-a-cluster

https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/5161